# How to add a column from one table to another in SQL?

Tags: sql, inner-join

Table1 has these columns: `country_id, location_id, street_address, city, state_province`

Table2 has: `country_id, country_name`

I want to display
`location_id, street_address, city, state_province, country_name`?

I want to add/append the `country_name` from Table2 to Table1. I can't get it to work.

How do I add a column from the one table to the other?

Comment: What is the (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question? You say you "want" 1 thing then you say you "want" a different thing. [mre] [ask] [Help] PS A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly" or "it is false that".

Comment: I cut & pasted that prefab ps comment of mine because the "basically" was, like what it summarized, not clear; the 2 unclear descriptions don't even seem to be saying the same thing--query vs update--which I told you my last comment. Voting is anonymous. Comments are ephemeral & comments that are thanks get deleted by moderators if flagged, and if short enough, by the system instantly on flagging. [Help] [meta] [meta.se] Although there was still no question in this post, I just saw that there was a question in the title that I moved into the post. Please don't put something only in the title.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter.

Comment: MySQL <> Oracle. Which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way would be to have a common value to join the tables:

Table 1 would have to have a field to identify which country it belongs to, like so:
`location_id, street_address, city, state_province, country_id`

Table 2 would need a primary key to identify the country code. So Table 2 would be like:
`country_id, country_name`

Then you could join on `country_id` to display the tables like you want.

The query would be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.country_name from table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 using(country_id);
```